How do i disable topology on weight painting mode?
I have this problem where when I choose an object and go into weight painting mode i can see all edges and cannot paint. This only happens on one object. I do not even know how I got this problem in a first place.

But when I go paint the body for example it is normal.

Can anyone elaborate what is happening and how to prevent this issue?

Deactivate the Paint Mask option:

